# Spatial/geometry types in Entity framework using postgresql and postGIS

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, postgis, devart, dotconnect

I need geometry types in my Entity Framework application. I've tried to follow [this](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/postgis-and-entity-framework.html#template) tutorial but I have had some issues and I'm not sure if it is because the tutorial is old or if I'm doing something wrong.
For example, under "Creating a New Entity C# Code Generation Template" it says

> select Entity C# in the "Load from existing template" drop-down list.

The closest thing I can find, how ever, is the "EntityObject" template. Also, the code in the EntityObject template is somewhat different and so I don't know if this will still work.
Also, the link to the template code is down so you have to transcribe the entire picture of code, which is inconvenient (especially if it turns out not to work).

My question is, is there a better/updated way to handle spatial datatypes with entity framework and postgresql in the year of 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for spatial/geometry data types in Entity Framework 5 and Entity Framework 6 will be available in the next build of [dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/). We plan to release the nearest build in a week or two.

Comment: Your constant presence here at stackoverflow and answer reaction time makes it much easier to decide what I'm going to do when the trial period for your products runs out.

Comment: Support for spatial data types in Entity Framework 5 and 6 is added in the new 6.7 version of dotConnect for PostgreSQL!
It can be downloaded from http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/download.html (trial version) or from Registered Users' Area (for users with active subscription only). For more information, please refer to http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27559 .